# How to combine two similar views into a single response?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two similar views that return the same serialized responses. The views are like this:

```
class GetFoos(generics.ListAPIView):
    # init stuff here

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Foo.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
        serializer = FooSerializer(queryset, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

class GetFooResponses(generics.ListAPIView):
    # init stuff here

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = FooResponse.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
        serializer = FooResponseSerializer(queryset, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And the serializers are like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ProfileInfoSerializer(source = 'owner.userprofile', read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user')

class FooResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source = 'foo.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source = 'foo.name')
    user = serializers.ProfileInfoSerializer(source = 'owner.userprofile', read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = FooResponse
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user')
```

And finally, the models look like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    owner = ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'foos')
    name = models.CharField()

class FooResponse(models.Model):
    owner = ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name = 'responses')
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, related_name = 'responses')
```

Since these two views and serializers return essentially the same data (an ID field, a name field and user profile info) and use the same request parameters (the current user), I'd like to combine these two into one. How do I do that? In the end, I'd like the serialized response to contain the results of both query sets.

Comment: Am I right that you want to make a view, which will return  AND Foo AND FooResponse serialized models?

Comment: @Paul Not exactly. I want to get all `Foo` objects where the user is the owner AND all `Foo` objects where there exists a `FooResponse` object where to user is the owner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `serializer.data` will be a list of dictionaries in your case, I'd try concatenating the results of both serializers for the response:

```
class GetFoosAndResponses(generics.ListAPIView):
    # init stuff here

    def list(self, request):
        foo_queryset = Foo.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        foo_serializer = FooSerializer(foo_queryset, many=True)

        foo_response_queryset = FooResponse.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        foo_response_serializer = FooResponseSerializer(foo_response_queryset, many=True)

        return Response(foo_serializer.data + foo_response_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Does this make sense? :)

Comment: Wow, the simplicity of Python never fails to amaze me. This works just like a charm!